# Trim qcow2 disk

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, qcow2

vps disk size does not updates on server when you delete files within vps.
For example one vps had 1TB usage, I deleted 800GB in that vps but vps disk size is  still 1TB on server.

Comment: maybe the file was already in use by process?

Comment: stopping and starting vps did not helped in reducing vps disk size on server.